Post Processing Bloom for mobile
I have recently asked a question where I wanted to know   why Post Processing effects lag so much on mobile. As I know now, it has to do with limited performance on mobile end devices.
So, I am asking if there is any website or app where you can apply bloom effect to the texture you want to bloom, so that it does not have to be redrawn every frame, but is rather set directly in the texture.
UPDATE:
This is what I want to bloom:

Also as a comment pointed out that I could use photoshop:
This is no option for me because I don't have photoshop installed and don't want to pay for it... I only have Krita that worked fine for drawing simple assets but I think it can't add bloom.

You can easily add a bloom effect to an image in an image editor like Photoshop, but it would help if you give an example of what you want to apply bloom to.

I have updated my question to include your comment. Thanks for reading my question! :)

I'd recommend editing your existing question instead of posting a new one about the same problem.

Are you using URP? If so, you can make a shader with glow.

I have imported URP, but is a shader really performant enough for mobile?


Open the ring in an image editor such as Photoshop or Gimp
Apply some blur
Add a black background behind the blurred ring
Save as a new image
In Unity, add the new image above the original ring.
Create a new material and select the shader "Mobile/Particles/Additive"
Apply the material to the image from step 5

